# how to make background image with round corners in a layout of android?

Tags: android, layout

i am trying to make a background image with rounded corners for setting it in layout.The problem is how to set a image in drawable XML for rounded corners rather than using a solid color.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
      <!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
      <solid android:color="#ffffff"/> 
       <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
   </shape>
```

Comment: using xml i don think you can achieve it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners

Comment: if u have few images then u can crop the image to particular corner radius using some image editing software like gimp etc...

Comment: i made it manually using http://anymaking.com/round-photo-corners-editor.thanks all of u for helping me...!

Comment: http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me: just add a file name **round_corners.xml** to ***drawable***

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/lemon" android:endColor="@color/lemon_cream" android:angle="90" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

add this `XML` to the file and enjoy round corners.